# Why does including a timezone into a MySQL DATETIME query with a VIEW make the fractional seconds not equivalent?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL 8 DB with a `DATETIME(4)` field, and I've run into a weird case around equivalency in a VIEW. I've worked around it but I'm not sure why it is happening and I'd like to understand why.

---

I have a table with a field: `date_time DATETIME(4)`. I have a VIEW where I turn this back into an ISO8601 string using `DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ') as date_time`.

If I insert a row with a date like `2017-04-22T20:47:05.33523Z`, and then the following query fails to find the row and I'm not sure why.

```
select * from EXAMPLE_VIEW where date_time >= '2017-04-22T20:47:05.335Z';
```

The following do work:

```
select * from EXAMPLE where date_time >= '2017-04-22T20:47:05.335Z';
select * from EXAMPLE where date_time >= '2017-04-22T20:47:05.335';
select * from EXAMPLE where date_time >= '2017-04-22T20:47:05.3350Z';

select * from EXAMPLE_VIEW where date_time >= '2017-04-22T20:47:05.335';
select * from EXAMPLE_VIEW where date_time >= '2017-04-22T20:47:05.3350Z'
```

Minimal example here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ak7LTLzH7UJGgmPWS85dRE/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you perform the comparison in the `VIEW` you are comparing as **strings**, not **dates**. When you format the datetime with `%f` you get 6 digits of microseconds i.e. `2017-04-22T20:47:05.335200Z`. Since you are comparing this as a string, the `>=` comparison with `'2017-04-22T20:47:05.335Z'` fails because `2` is less than `Z`.

The reason this test works in query 1 is that `'2017-04-22T20:47:05.335Z'` gets converted to a date (resulting in `2017-04-22T20:47:05.335000Z`) before comparison, and that is less than `2017-04-22T20:47:05.335200Z`.